# C# - .Find() Null vs Empty List condition

Tags: c#

I have a .Find statement like so:

```
MyObject obj = existingObjs.Find(x => x.listA == currentObj.listA &&
                                      x.listB == currentObj.listB);
```

Unfortunately "obj" is always null because my "currentObj" has a listB = null but "x.listB" is always an empty list. I want to treat null and empty list as the same thing, how would I put that into my .Find statement?

I tried something like so but, it is returning a bool instead of an obj so it won't compile.

```
MyObject obj = existingObjs.Find(x => x.listA == currentObj.listA &&
                                     (x.listB == null ? null : currentObj.listB));
```

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve, using == to compare things that you say are lists? Tell me, what would you expect this `bool b` to be: `var list1 = "123".ToList(); var list2 = "123".ToList(); bool b = (list1 == list2);`

Answer (score 1):

Some points to note:

- you should rather not use == for comparing complicated objects like lists, since `==` tests for reference equality, not the structure (e.g. whether elements on the list are the same). For comparing lists you could use `Enumerable.SequenceEqual`
- mixing null and empty list in the same variable is a bad practice that will hit you in many places just like here, but for handling null vs empty there is nullish coalescing operator `x.listB ?? Enumerable.Empty()` that will always return enumerable object that you can use for comparisons
- all of this should be put into `bool Equals(MyObject other)` method

for example

```
    using System;
    using System.Linq;
   
    class MyObject<T> : IEquatable<MyObject<T>> {
      public bool Equals(MyObject<T> other) {
        if (other == null) 
          return false;
        return ListsEqual(listA, other.listA) &&
               ListsEqual(listB, other.listB);
      }
      bool ListsEqual(IList<T> l1, IList<T> l2) {
        return Enumerable.SequenceEqual(ListOrEmpty(l1), ListOrEmpty(l2));
      }
      IEnumerable<T> ListOrEmpty(IList<T> li) { 
        return li ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>();
      }
      IList<T> listA;
      IList<T> listB;
    }
```

Comment: An excellent answer, but I'd suggest a code sample if you can provide one. Especially if you can provide a sample implementation of the `Equals` implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the conditional operator:

```
currentObj.listB == null ? 
    !Any(x.listB) :
    Enumerable.SequenceEqual(currentObj.listB, x.listB)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use null-coalescing operator to make sure array in `currentObject` will be empty arrays when they are `null` and then compare them:

```
currentObject.listA ??= Array.Empty<ListAType>();
currentObject.listB ??= Array.Empty<ListBType>();
MyObject obj = existingObjs.Find(x => Enumerable.SequenceEqual(x.listA, currentObj.listA) &&
                                      Enumerable.SequenceEqual(x.listB, currentObj.listB));
```